# Исключение текущего пункта меню

Tags: cms, modx, revo

Как исключать из меню ссылку на страницу, на которой в данный момент находимся через pdomenu в Modx revo? Как пример, у меня сейчас такая заготовка (-14 это я исключил пункт меню который нужно всегда исключать, не обращайте внимания):

```
[[pdoMenu?
   &parents         = `2`
   &limit           = `0`
   &level           = `0`
   &showUnpublished = `0`
   &resources       = `-14`
   &tplOuter        = `@INLINE <ul>[[+wrapper]]</ul>`
   &tpl             = `@INLINE <li><a href="[[+link]]">[[+menutitle]]</a></li>`
]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо использовать `&tplHere` - Чанк оформления текущего пункта меню.

```
&tplHere= `@INLINE `
```

Т.е. вместо текущего пункта меню ничего не выводить

Документация по сниппету: https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/pdotools/snippetyi/pdomenu

Answer (score 0):

Дополню рабочий вариант, данный @Tunker, еще одним.

Можно добавить в исключения ID текущего отображаемого ресурса, дополнительно к ресурсу с ID=14:

```
&resources = `-14,-[[*id]]`
```